# Android emoticons viewable in my php website?

Tags: php

got a really weird thing here, it's not a problem but I don't understand it!

Basically I have a website created in only php, html and CSS. I coded an in-game private messaging system, a user messaged me and I noticed the emoticons they used with their tablet are appearing on my game!! See the image: [image]

How is this possible? Shouldn't I have to code the emoticons into my site for it to happen??

My site is only set to use "text/css" as the 'language', are these icons part of that set? :S

Comment: Probably just UTF-8 characters... like so 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of emoticons have UTF-8 and Unicode equivalents. The code is interpreted natively by the browser and, on mobile/tablet devices, the native apps assign their own image to that specific UTF-8/Unicode code.

Thumbs-up sign () is "U+1F44D" in Unicode and "\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D" in UTF-8, for example - and if you view that on other devices you may see an image emoticon replace it instead of the black and white native interpretation in your browser.

You'll be surprised how many emoticons will render natively on your browser - there's a comprehensive list here:

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

You can even use them as CSS rules, or DIV names, or even part of a URL if you want!

Comment: Wow, I had no idea! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped!